# Minimum number which is co-prime of all elements of the array

Tags: arrays, primes, number-theory

I came across this question in an assessment and couldn't solve it optimally.
You are given n numbers A1, A2, A3..An. Find a minimum number P(P>1) such that P is a co-prime with all of the given numbers.

**Example:**
A = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
P would be 7 because gcd(2,7) = gcd(3,7) = gcd(4,7) = gcd(5,7) = gcd(6,7) = 1

**Constraints:**

> 1 <= N <= 10^5
> 1 <= A <= 10^6

I tried finding the answer by checking with the prime numbers one by one(I generated prime numbers by sieve of eratosthenes).

Can anybody tell the optimal approach?

Comment: How do you know your method isn't already optimal?

Comment: It was in online assessment, I could't pass all the test cases.

Comment: Ok, then here is what I suspect is an optimal approach just for these constraints. First note that P will be the smallest prime that doesn't divide any of the A_i. Using a modified sieve of eratosthenes precompute an array S, where S[i] = set of primes that divide i, i<10\*\*6, ignoring multiplicity and also retain the sieve array B where presumably B[q] == true if and only if q is prime. Now proceed through each A_i, setting B[r] = false for each prime p in S[A_i]. After finishing processing the A_i look for the first index j for which B[j] == true. j should be P.